# AJAX returns a different result than the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

so I'm using JQuery's .getJSON to get a JSON from an api, the request are made on my localhost to a remote server.

When I access the remote server from the browser itself the data is ok, but when I use JQuery's getJSON the data is different, like there are no cookies even though there are.

I've thought that it's related to the cross origion policy stuff so I've tried using "Ajax Cross Origin" and it didn't help.

So what happens is that for example, when I access the server via the browser, it returns (this is ok)-

```
  {
  "id": "7"
  }
```

And when I use a JQuery's getJSON (this is wrong)-

```
 {
  "id": null
 }
```

What makes it even weirder is that when I use Postman rest client then I get the right data.

TIA

Comment: Does the remote server depend on the cookies, i.e. that you're logged in?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be open the developer tools in the browser, before the getJSON request is made. Then (e.g. in Chrome) click on the Network tab. Find the Http Get request made for the getJSON call, and click on it. Inspect any errors, check that the cookies were sent correctly, check the response data, right click the Url and open in new tab, what result do you get?